# Changing CSP Type for Certificate in Windows

Tags: windows, certificate, private-key, pki

After executing the below command

```
openssl engine capi -t -post list_options:33 -post list_certs
```

Output

```
Private Key Info:
   Provider Name:  Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0, Provider Type 1
```

Now i need to change this CSP type to  `Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider`.

Is that possible ?

And Also at what point of time it is decided that this certificate will bind/register to a CSP ? Does that occur at the time of certficate and private key creation or it happens while Signing the Certificate from CA ?

Answer (score 0):

No,

a CSP will define, among others, the key size. If you used the Base Provider to generate an RSA key it will be 512 bits will the Enhanced Provider uses 1024 bits.

This is decided at a key generation. Microsoft CAs can enforce the CSP used before signing the certificate.

Comment: I am using this cmd "openssl req -out clientreq -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout clientkey" for key generation. But in this i am not giving the name of any CSP. So it is decided that this private key will bind to a particular CSP ?

Comment: If you are generating the certificate with Openssl it won´t be stored in the windows registry and hence won´t have any CSP associated.